# Expressing a subtype relation between enumeration types in Z3

Tags: types, z3, smt

What's the best way to express a subtype relation between enumeration types in Z3?

Specifically, I want to do something like the following:

```
(declare-datatypes () ((Animal Eagle Snake Scorpion)))
```

and then create a new subtype:

```
(declare-datatypes () ((Mammal Cat Rat Bat)))
```

so that an assertion that there are 4 distinct constants of type Animal is SAT, but an assertion that there are 4 distinct constants of type Mammal is UNSAT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Z3 has no direct support for subtype (subsort) relationships.
I can see two ways to model them in Z3.

For example, you can have an enumeration sort `Animal` that contains all animals. Then, you define predicates such as: `is-mammal`, `is-reptile`, etc.

Here is the script that uses this approach:

```
(set-option :produce-models true)
(declare-datatypes () ((Animal Eagle Snake Scorpion Cat Rat Man)))

(define-fun is-mammal ((x Animal)) Bool
        (or (= x Cat) (= x Rat) (= x Man)))

(declare-const a1 Animal)
(declare-const a2 Animal)
(declare-const a3 Animal)
(declare-const a4 Animal)


(assert (distinct a1 a2 a3 a4))
(check-sat)
; sat
(get-model)

; now, we constraint a1, a2, a3 and a4 to be mammals.
(assert (is-mammal a1))
(assert (is-mammal a2))
(assert (is-mammal a3))
(assert (is-mammal a4))
(check-sat)
; unsat
```

Another solution uses datatypes for defining enumeration sorts and union sorts.
That is, we declare one datatype for each animal class: `MammalType`, `ReptileType`, etc.
Each of them is an enumeration type.  Then, we declare an `union` datatype: `AnimalType`.
This datatype contains a constructor for each animal class: `Mammal`, `Reptile`, etc.
Z3 automatically creates a predicate `is-[constructor-name]` (recognizer) for each constructor: `is-Mammal`, `is-Reptile`, etc.
We name accessors as "Animal2Class": `Animal2Mammal`, `Animal2Reptile`, etc. You can find more information about datatypes at http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorial/guide.
Here is the script using this encoding:

```
(set-option :produce-models true)

(declare-datatypes () ((AveType Eagle Sparrow)))
(declare-datatypes () ((ReptileType Snake)))
(declare-datatypes () ((ArachnidType Scorpion Spider)))
(declare-datatypes () ((MammalType Cat Rat Man)))

(declare-datatypes () ((AnimalType 
                        (Ave (Animal2Ave AveType))
                        (Reptile (Animal2Reptile ReptileType))
                        (Arachnid (Animal2Arachnid ArachnidType))
                        (Mammal (Animal2Mammal MammalType)))))

(declare-const a1 AnimalType)
(declare-const a2 AnimalType)
(declare-const a3 AnimalType)
(declare-const a4 AnimalType)

(assert (distinct a1 a2 a3 a4))
(check-sat)
; sat
(get-model)

; now, we constraint a1, a2, a3 and a4 to be mammals.
(assert (is-Mammal a1))
(assert (is-Mammal a2))
(assert (is-Mammal a3))
(assert (is-Mammal a4))
(check-sat)
; unsat
```

Comment: Leo, do have a hunch about which of the two encodings would perform better? Would they scale differently?

Comment: In the current version of Z3, encoding one is probably better in most cases. I would use encoding one, and encode enumeration types using integers or bit-vectors.